# Trying to strip html from Datatables during export

Tags: javascript, datatable, export-to-excel

I'm using datatables exactly as the example [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html). So to export data I used a function that allows me to change `<br>` with newlines in excel.
I used this:

```
return column === 5 ? data.replace( /<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\n"): data;
```

However when I try to add a second change I want to make to a different column it doesn't work... I tried adding this right below the first working replacement:

```
return column === 1 ? data.replace( /<.*?>/ig, ""): data;
```

I want to basically strip all html tags after first changing the `<br>` to newlines. But as my code is now, **the second part just gets ignored during export...** Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Here is my full code:

```
var fixNewLine = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, column, row ) {
                return column === 5 ? data.replace( /<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\n"): data;
                return column === 1 ? data.replace( /<.*?>/ig, ""): data;
            }
        }
    }
};

var t2e = $('#table2excel').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons:[
            $.extend( true, {}, fixNewLine, {
                extend: 'excelHtml5'
            } ),
            'pdf', 'print', 'copy', 'csv' //, 'excel'
        ]

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have multiple return statement in code only first one will be executed, try this:

```
var fixNewLine = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, column, row ) {
                if (column === 5) {
                    data = data.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\n");
                }
                return column === 1 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, ""): data;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow man thanks! This worked. But now I tried to do this to all my columns:
First change `<br>` with newlines, and then remove the remaining html.
So I tried this inside the body-function: `data = data.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/ig, "\n");  data = data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, ""); return data;`  But it didn't save the newlines properly... Do you know any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement to deal with each column individually worked really well for me. See my usage below...

```
var fixNewLine = { 
    exportOptions: { 
        format: { 
            body: function ( data, row, column, node ) { 
                 switch(column){
                    case 1 :  return column === 1 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break;
                    case 2 :  return column === 2 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break;
                    case 3 :  return column === 3 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break;
                    case 4 :  return column === 4 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break;
                    case 5 :  return column === 5 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break;
                    case 6 :  return column === 6 ? data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") : data; break; 
                    default : return data; break;
                }
            } 
        } 
    }
};
```

Comment: you don't need `break` after a return statement in the final `default` case. : )

Comment: you're doing something weird... when you have a `switch` then `case 1` will always be `column === 1` so you don't need to make an extra check.

You can rewrite that whole case statement with just `return (column > 0 && column < 7) : data.replace(/<.*?>/ig, "") ? data`