# Customize data when export jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables, export-to-excel

I am using jQuery [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) in Laravel and I want to use the export functionality of the plugin.

Now my problem is that in my table I have some HTML so that instead of actual text I render a tickbox.

Example

```
<td>
    <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}">
        <i class="material-icons md-18">check_box</i>
    </span>
</td>
```

When I export this table in Excel I get the value of the td 'check_box' so the excel looks like this

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
| Firstname | Lastname | Option 1  | Option 2  |  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
| Christos  | Savva    | check_box | check_box |  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
| Second    | Person   | check_box | check_box |  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
| Third     | Person   | check_box | check_box |  |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-----------+--+
```

Obviously this makes no sense in an excel file whereas on screen is fine because I render the icons.

As per the documentation I tried to use the [Format output data - export options](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-function.html)

```
var buttonCommon = {
    exportOptions: {
        format: {
            body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
                //Do stuff to replace check_box with word Yes
                //or no
                return data
            }
        }
    }
};
```

And here comes the problem. When I return data from my function it returns the whole html block inside the td.

So the excel looks like this

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| Firstname | Lastname | Option 1                                                      | Option 2                                                      |  |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| Christos  | Savva    | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> |  |
|           |          |                                                               |                                                               |  |
|           |          | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       |  |
|           |          |                                                               |                                                               |  |
|           |          | </span>                                                       | </span>                                                       |  |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| Second    | Person   | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> |  |
|           |          | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       |                                                               |  |
|           |          | </span>                                                       | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       |  |
|           |          |                                                               |                                                               |  |
|           |          |                                                               | </span>                                                       |  |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+
| Third     | Person   | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> | <span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}"> |  |
|           |          |                                                               |                                                               |  |
|           |          | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       | <i class="material-icons md-18">yes</i>                       |  |
|           |          |                                                               |                                                               |  |
|           |          | </span>                                                       | </span>                                                       |  |
+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+--+
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986288/trying-to-strip-html-from-datatables-during-export

Comment: You only show snippets for "checked". How does the HTML look when a pseudo checkbox not is checked?

Comment: When checkbox is checked the I just change the color with css, I make it green, if not checked the color is gray


@tschitsch I will check it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume the HTML is rendered. i.e `<span class="{{($r->submitted == 1)?'checkbox-checked':''}}">` is rendered as `<span class="checkbox-checked">` or `<span class="">` :

```
exportOptions: {
  format: {
    body: function ( data, row, column, node ) {
      if (![2,3].indexOf(column)) {
        return $('span', data).hasClass('checkbox-checked')
          ? 'yes'
          : 'no'
      }
      return data
    }
  }    
}
```

Comment: I will actually mark your solution as the answer because I didn't know that this

`$(data, 'span')`

can turn the string I was getting into a JS object, so I could easily do

`let span = $(data, 'span').html()` and do what I needed to get the correct output

Could you please let me know where did you find that? Is it a jquery thing or datatable thing
Thanks

Comment: Actually it is the other way around :) Have updated the answer. It was just "syntactic sugar" to make it more clear, in your case it really doesnt matter since `<span>` is the parent element anyway, but if you wanted to work on the `<i>` child element it would be `$('i', data)` == children `<i>` elements  I think it has been in jQuery since forever,  i.e always. Normal common syntax, have nothing to do with DT.

Comment: Thank you! I was console logging data and since it was a sting I couldn't do much with it. I didn't came across this before `$('i', data)`. You gave me the solution in 2 words :D.